# HTTP 304 loading SVG via jQuery.html()

Tags: html, svg

I have an SVG logo wrapped in an anchor on a site being served in several test environments. In all environments except the latest one we built, this logo loads fine. In the latest environment the SVG logo fails to load in Chrome and Safari but loads fine in Firefox. I cannot figure out the root cause or where even to start looking.

The code in question resembles this

```
<a href="/" id="logo" title="home"><img src="/images/logo.svg"></a>
```

In Chrome and Safari, the server returns HTTP 200 but the response contains no data. The result is a broken image icon.

[image: broken image icon]

My first thought was that it was a file permission problem. I tried `chmod 777` and `chmod 644` and `chown root` and `chown www-data`. No effect.

My second thought was that it was a browser caching issue. But running in Incognito Mode in both Chrome and Safari and clearing the browsers' caches has no effect.

Even more strange to me is that if I open the SVG directly via `https://ourhost/images/logo.svg` in Safari or Chrome, then the response is correct.

The site is being served from a locally hosted  Wordpress on Apache2.

**UPDATE**: As [Manivannan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3834688/manivannan) realized, this has nothing to do with jQuery. I've edited that out

Comment: maybe you have a base tag somewhere in your html... What happends if you open the brocken image in another tab?

Comment: To me it sounds like the SVG is not being served with the correct MIME type.  Check the SVG file in your browser tools Net tab and make sure that the Content-type response header is "image/svg+xml".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not problem with jQuery. It is better to convert svg to data-URL and use through CSS background style('logobg-svg') for the svg supported browsers and use png/jpg background image class('logobg') for non SVG supported browsers.

```
HTML
----
SVG Supported browsers     : <i role=image class='logobg-svg' />
NON SVG Supported browsers : <i role=image class='logobg' />

CSS
---
.logobg-svg{
   background : url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg ... > ...')
}
.logobg{
   background : url('../image/logo.png')
}
```

Comment: I'll give it a try. Yeah, I realized, too, that it wasn't a jQuery issue and was updating the question as you answered!